# LIBREOFFICE calc file can't be open by different computer

Tags: microsoft-office, libreoffice-calc

I have a .ods file on my USB drive and want to edit it at home and at work. But all documents I create are "stuck" to the computer I created it on. I have tried to save the file with password for reading and edit, but when I insert "edit password" it says. "File is write protected, want to open as copy?"

Comment: Can you clarify how MS Office relates to the question?  Are you trying to open the LO Calc file in Excel?

Comment: Try to test it with a different usb drive. Maybe the complete device is write-protected.

Comment: I have this problem in libre, exel, and open. Its not only my computer/usb drive. Have many other documents,script in usb working fine. Every computer at work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *Save as...* dialog and select a format suitable for the recipient, e.g. .XLS for older Excel versions.

[image]

Comment: Seems to work. Need to test it more. Do you know why this is happening? Is it not suppose to edit files on different computers?

Comment: I can confirm that this work. but i will not sett it as answer because im not happy with it.